# How do I reduce my dog's excessive shedding?

Tags: dogs, grooming, shedding

I have a three and a half year old mutt, who sheds excessive amounts of hair. My clothing and floors are covered with puffs of her hair, and I vacuum and use lint rollers daily.

I have tried fish oil, adding salmon to her diet, frequent grooming, bathing, using a furminator, and everything else I can think of. The vet tells me that my dog is perfectly healthy, so it's really just an inconvenience, not a disorder.

(If it matters, she's a mutt. Part hound. [Here](https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5792/23699210421_79e5095e52_b.jpg) is a photo.)

How can I reduce or contain the shedding?

Comment: Have you tried changing foods?

The furminator is really the way to go, the first time you use it though you may be brushing for a loooooong time. If you stop brushing and are still getting a lot of undercoat you need to brush more.

Keep in mind changing seasons can make your dog shed extra as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have taken most of the steps recommended to minimise shedding. These are (for reference):

- Regular grooming: brushing will remove some or most of the loose hair
- Improving diet: dogs may have allergies to a certain food causing them to shed more. Higher quality food means better skin which means less shedding even without possible allergies.
- Vet visit: your dog may be sick causing them to shed more.

If you have tried all of that it is possible that your dog is just a shedder, some breeds do shed more than others. Dogs also shed more during season changes so this may be aggravating the matter.